# was predicated upon an eventual U.S. withdrawal

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Biden noted that violent attacks in Afghanistan had paused in recent months due to a deal negotiated by the Trump administration with Taliban leaders that **was predicated upon an eventual U.S. withdrawal**.

Source: ABC News  [Biden says he did not see a way to withdraw from Afghanistan without 'chaos ensuing'](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/biden-withdraw-afghanistan-chaos-ensuing/story?id=79507930)

Does "was predicated upon an eventual U.S. withdrawal" mean "was **based on** an eventual U.S. withdrawal"?
Dictionaries define "predicate" as "to base (behavior, etc.) on some stated belief, etc.:" Hence the guess.

Answer (score 1):

It's the "belief" mentioned in that definition that is the important thing.

Taliban leaders signed a deal with the Trump administration and stopped their violent attacks because they believed the deal's assertion that the US would eventually withdraw.

Comment: Thanks. But you've not answered my question of whether "predicated upon" means "based on" there.

Comment: Didn't I? It's *based on their belief* that the US would eventually withdraw.